# Asp.net Server code executes two times and returns failed callback method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Im calling server code (c#) by jQuery ajax method or ajax pagemethods. While calling, server code executes two times and returns failed callback method.

This code is not working in recently hosted new server. In existing servers, this code working without any problem and returning success callback method.

JS Code:

```
var myVal = 'Test val';
var input = {
    'val1': myVal
};
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'MyPage.aspx/MyFunction',
    data: JSON.stringify(input),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'Application/json',
    success: QCErrorResult,
    error: QCErrorFailedMethod
});
```

OR

JS Code:

```
PageMethods.MyFunction(myVal, QCErrorResult, QCErrorFailedMethod);
```

C# Code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
public static string MyFunction(string val1)
{
    // My code here
}
```

Same issue while calling my api by jquery ajax.

Comment: Have you tried adding [httppost] to your C# method.

Answer (score 0):

In App_Start/RouteConfig comment the line settings.AutoRedirectMode =RedirectMode.Permanent if its there. For multiple times calling, check the post backs of the page.

Comment: app_start setting is not available in my project. I'm using VisualStudio 2008 for this project. Could you please explain in deeper.